# C# application memory leak

Tags: c#, windows, dll, memory-leaks, taskmanager

I would like to ask about memory leak with my C# application. I created an application for get and store data into database. My Application is communicate with another application (client for measurement) through the special DLL library (using WINAPI). The DLL library is working as an TCPInterface.

But, I have memory leak (Im sure, the problem is my application):

After longer time (few days of measurement 24h/day) I open task manager and:

- physical memory in Windows task manager is full (after longer time with full memory, computer is working very slow or freeze),
- My Application is using about 100MB of RAM (same like on the start and not increase),
- Measurement application is using about 120MB of RAM (same, like on the start and not increase),
- another processes in task manager are negligible.

And I dont know, where I lost about 4GB of RAM (when I compare list of running processes in Task Manager and Summary of available physical memory).

I tryed ProcessExplorer but without result.

Q1:
Is it possible, that some threads running inside my application are not calculated in memory information of my application in task manager?

Q2:
If the DLL using some physical memory and my application is calling the DLL through WINAPI, where will be counted the amount of used memory of this DLL?
- to my application? ...or where? -how can I see it?

THX for each help.

Comment: Have you tried to profile your app using a memory profiler? Create two snapshots, one just after the app start and one e.g. after 1 hour of work. Then compare the snapshots, so you can find out whether your app leaks memory and if so - where exactly.

Comment: thank you for the tip, Im goying to try it. I have installed .NET Memory Profiler

Comment: This question might be of some help: https://superuser.com/q/906161

Comment: also you can take memory dump from you task manager(Right Click One Proceess=>Select Create dump file). and import memory dump in vs2015.you can see there object counts and which object consuming more memory.

Comment: Exactly, this is my problem.

Comment: I will also try It, now Im trying the memory profiler. After few hours I will take a snaphost and we will see.